# Is there an idiomatic way to structure a Lua project?

Tags: plugins, lua, neovim

I'm creating a *Neovim plugin* in **Lua** and am looking for a reasonable way to structure my projects for testing, loading modules from Luarocks for development, and distributing this to users.

For example, in a **Javascript** project it's common to see something like the following:

```
README.md
node_modules/
dist/
src/
test/
```

After reviewing a number of Github repos for Lua projects, I'm not seeing a common pattern, so suggestions or boilerplates are welcome. **Many thanks**.

Comment: there is no standard way to do this. maybe Neovim has some guidelines for their plugins you can follow but usually you just do what makes sense.

Comment: The short answer is no. You organize the code the way you think is sutiable. Check popular lua plugins such as nvim-cmp or telescope.nvim to get some inspiration.